# OOP language design attribute symbol

Tags: language-design

I am designing a language, and wondering which character (or string) to use to represent that something is an attribute of something else.

In all languages I have used, this is done with a dot - `my_class_instance.attribute`.

However, in this language, I want to have what would usually be methods as syntactic sugar for normal functions, like so:

```
x.f(y, z).g(a, b).h(p, q)
```

is the same thing as

```
x = f(x, y, z)
x = g(x, a, b)
x = h(x, p, q)
```

However, if I also use `.` to show that an attribute belongs to a class I think that will get confusing, so I'm looking for another symbol for that purpose (or another solution).

Currently I am thinking that I should use either the apostrophe - `instance'attribute` - which shows ownership in a clear way, but means it can't be used for strings, the backtick - `` instance`attribute `` - kind of looks like an apostrophe, which is good in the sense it shows ownership, but bad in the sense it could be mistaken for one, and is less commonly typed, and therefore likely to be slower to be typed (and missing from some keyboards).

Alternatively, are there any symbols I could replace the dot used for the syntatic sugar inplace function calling thing with?

Comment: Doesn't the last assignment win?  I don't get why you want to assign to `x` three times.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Each assignment changes the value of `x`, so when `g` is called on `x` it is different to if it had been called on it at the start, as `f(x, y, z)` is not necessarily the same as `x` on that line.

Comment: Naturally each assignment changes the value of `x`.  I can only assume there is some code in between each assignment since the last assignment wins, making the first two assignments pointless.  In any case, your example with three lines assigning to x is going to be clearer to most programmers.  Clarity is king.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What do you mean by "wins"? If I do `x = 7` then `x = x + 5` then `x = x * 2` then the last assignment isn't the only important one.

Comment: hard to believe that you're designing a new OOP language and the only question you have is whether to use a dot or not...

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe: How is that hard to believe? Many popular languages differ little in semantics, leading designers to place undue emphasis on syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the dot-method and dot-attribute syntax isn't mutually exclusive precisely then when you require parens on method calls. Consider this piece of Java:

```java
class Foo {
  int bar = 1;

  int bar() { return 2; }
}

...
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.bar;   // the attribute
foo.bar(); // the method
```

Of course, using this language feature can't be recommended. So the real question is how you are going to disambiguate method calls from your “inplace functions”. The probably best way is to use some form of *interpolation*. Consider this Perl:

```perl
my $function = sub {
  my ($object, $arg) = @_;
  return $object + $arg;
};
my $x = 40;
say $x->$function(2); #=> 42
```

where `$x->$y(@z)` is syntactic sugar for `&$y($x, @z)`. This syntax is orthogonal to method calls which would look like `$x->y` or `$x->y()`. Perl can pull this off because variables have a `$` prefix.

Using a similar syntax might be recommendable, so you might end up with

```
foo.bar;            // attribute
foo.bar();          // method
foo.$bar();         // inplace function
foo.{bar || baz}(); // alternative interpolation marker
```

You are right, this is confusing. Consider carefully what expressiveness you gain by using inplace functions. In the case of Perl, the variable may contain the name of the method, thus allowing data to decide which method gets called, which in contrast to the above syntactic sugar is actually useful.

```perl
$foo->bar;
# the same as
my $meth = "bar";
$foo->$meth;
```

Your “inplace methods” overload this with very diferent meaning. It would make more sense for `x.$y(z)` to mean `y(x, z)` (as the equivalent Perl). Your example with multiple chains would then become

```
x = x.$f(y, z).$g(a, b).$h(p, q)
// the same as
x = h(g(f(x, y, z), a, b), p, q)
```

Note that here the `.$` apparently has characteristics of a *feed operator*. In Perl6, these two lines are equivalent:

```perl
@input ==> grep { $_ % 3 == 0 } ==> map { $_ * 2 } ==> my @processed;
# the same as
my @processed = map({ $_ * 2 }, grep({ $_ % 3 == 0 }, @input));
```

**Summary:** come up with a very good reason why you want to invoke functions as if  they were methods, and choose sensible semantics (esp. the auto-assign looks like a bad idea if you've ever programmed functional).
Then, there are various syntactic possibilities to call arbitrary functions on your objects, ranging from “interpolation” `x.$y()` to operators that emphasize dataflow like `==>`.